# Controlling AC light bulb intensity

Tags: ac, control, light

I saw in some movies that indoor light intensity is controlled with human presence and distance from the sensor (the lower the distance, the higher is the light intensity).

I am very interested to know if I have a correct assumptions for how all of that controlling works.

Are they using PIR sensors or some other type of sensors to measure the distance and presence of human in room? Are there any ready-made solution similar to this?

I want to make that controlling circuit and connect it to home AC network, is it easy to that, or it's not easy as I think?

Comment: Without a referece to a real world installation, this is just asking for guesses.

Comment: Why would you want it to get brighter as you got closer? Are you trying to blind people?

Comment: Maybe to reduce power consumption and to remove wall switches from use ?

Comment: We have a PIR-based system for turning the lights on in our open-plan office. Every now and again we've all been still enough that it switches off, and we have to wave our arms around in the dark until it comes on again.

Comment: @Andyaka: "*Why would you want it to get brighter as you got closer?*". Maybe this can be stated the other way: "you want the light to be less powerful where you are not", so that fully ON lights are those close to you. That's exactly the reason behind the principle explained by SeBen.

Answer (score 10):

This can easily be implemented using arduino (or some other micro-controller), an ultrasonic distance sensor, a triac (with proper opto-isolated driver such as MOC3021), a zero cross detection circuit made using another opto-isolator such as K814P and an incandescent bulb.

Read something about [phase control](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ACPhaseControl). It's like a pwm for ac power source. You can use this optically isolated zero cross detection circuit:

[image: ZCD]

This will give you a 100 Hz or 120 Hz signal depending upon where you live. This is one of the prime ingredients for phase control.

In order to drive the bulb, you will need a triac (electromechanical relay won't cut it). Here is a circuit that you can use:

[image: triac control]

When Triac1 pin is HIGH, TRIAC_LOAD1 gets connected to LIVE1. Other end of LOAD is directly connected to neutral so the load turns ON. However, it won't turn off as soon as you send the TRIAC1 pin LOW. [Read more on triacs](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/power/triac.html).

With this circuit and an arduino, you can make an incandescent bulb glow at different brightness levels (CFL and most LED bulbs won't work).

Now the last thing that remains is [using your ultrasonic sensor to measure distance](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/UltrasonicSensor).

Once you know that, you can combine all these things to get the desired effect. As soon as you move towards the distance sensor, increase the brightness of the bulb using phase control.

Comment: How will you differentiate between the furniture and walls and the people?

Comment: @transistor, the addition of a thermal based movement sensor would confirm a human as moving. Or just applying memory to see if there is a change in position of any type would be sufficient to remove false positives from furniture.

Comment: Obligatory warning about AC circuits and component selection goes here..

Comment: Why do you need an Arduino?

Answer (score 5):

Since this was in a movie, they probably had stage hands manually controlling dimmers as the actors moved around.

In any case, that's what I'd do if faced with those specs, and I'm a professional EE.

Comment: But it is great idea to make it real.

Comment: @Junior don't assume many other folk will think it's a great idea.

Comment: My thought exactly regarding keeping the stage hand busy. There is a reason movies have a high production price tag!!

Answer (score 2):

You may come across lighting that behaves as you describe in modern car-parks, street-lighting etc, especially the more modern LED varieties being installed in the last couple of years.

You will notice these behave differently to the old style "switch on at full brightness when you're near them, wait a few minutes, then switch off" PIR systems of elder years. The modern lights fade from a low 10/20% level up to full brightness as you approach, and will fade back down to a lower level once you leave the vincinity.

These use a more modern type of PIR sensor known as a presence sensor or presence detector, however they are based on the same technology. The difference being the latter is far more sensitive, splitting the area under detection into as many as hundreds of thousands of small squares. Using the higher sensitivity and higher accuracy method of detection allows the sensor to "see" people or objects approaching the light fitting, and also leaving. It also can detect minute movements. This allows perhaps a couple to stand near the light in conversation for 10 minutes without actually moving about, still triggering the lighting to stay on.

Take a look here for more information: http://www.theben.de/en/Presence-detector-for-the-energy-efficient-lighting-control

Answer (score 1):

Completing Whiskeyjack's answer since TRIACs won't work with most LED fixtures, since LEDs themselves operate in lower voltages (and your LED lamp is really a usually non-isolating switch-mode power supply connected to a bunch of LEDs) you can skip the ready-made lamps and go directly to high-power LED chips controlled using power MOSFETs, using the PWM signal from your Arduino board (or anything similar).